# My college laptop went kaput and I don't have any writing samples to include in my grad school application. Do you have suggestions?

Tags: masters, application, writing

Practically all programs require a writing sample from applicants. I'm preparing to apply by the end of 2022 but I'm stressed about this aspect of it since I have very few options.

The hard drive in the laptop I used in college is unsalvageable, so I don't have any papers from college where I was the only author.

I can think of two samples:

1. a senior design report on google drive that may be 20+ pages (that is, if I still have access, plus it was a group paper)
2. a report from a work experience (also 20+ pages) with my name as an author, though a coworker wrote it. However, I was involved in the work that gathered the data used in writing the report so it seems fair to use, if necessary.

I contacted my university's technology center to see if they can share any papers I may have saved on their network. Otherwise, I'm struggling to think of options. I don't write reports in my current job. Aside from what I listed above, the only other writing samples are cover letters for job applications.

Comment: What are the requirements for your writing sample (e.g., can it be just a page or two)? How much time do you have?

Comment: @cag51

Trying to have everything submitted by December 1. 

Requirements vary. Someone told me to go through my college email to see if there are papers. I hadn't thought of that and found some already. They're a few years old, but will save me from having to write something entirely new. So I may have found my solution!